# audio streaming in Android with the MediPlayer class

Tags: android, media-player

I'm testing the audio streaming in Android with the MediPlayer class. I want to develop an application to play web radios. The streaming over http works. The code below work fine on emulator with Froyo(v. 2.2) but didn't work with Eclair (v. 2.1)

```
// in onStartCommand   
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);  
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

// in onPrepared
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But my app should also work on Eclair (v. 2.1) and I want to know how MediaPlayer work on it.

Someone has any experience with audio streaming in Android?

Comment: What happens when you try it? No sound? Crash?

Comment: It didn't work. Method onPrepared never invoke. So when I simple put mediaPlayer.start() after mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() also nothing happened - music was not playing.

Comment: You are probably affected by this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7186

Comment: I just have tested my app on Donut (v. 1.6), but it also not work and issue the same - onPrepared never invoke.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When I declared onPreparedListener my track was already loaded. So  onPreparedListener didn't work..