# android progressive streaming for locally recorded audio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am recording certain audio files using the builtin media recording API , here is the relevant code for recording

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

then I upload said file to server , 
now when I try to play it , mediaplayer is simply unable to do so.

here is streaming code

```
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
 mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

what settings should I use to be able to allow streaming for audio.

Comment: Do you invoke mediaPlayer.start() in onPrepared? It helps more if you discribe error more fully. Or may be you have the same [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050637/audio-streaming-in-android-with-the-mediplayer-class)

Comment: I have done all of that, no luck though, there is no error, the stream just won't play